# Need to get value from DropDownListFor asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, combobox

I have combobox in view and I need to get select value in combobox.

Code View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.servicesModel, (SelectList)ViewBag.serviceNames, new { @id = "listNames" })
```

Code action that added values in combobox(I know, I missed the symbol in database when created table):

```
var servicesDetails = dbModel.SERVICES.ToList();

        ViewBag.serviceNames = new SelectList(servicesDetails, "iIdSevices", "vName");
```

I have form, press button and after that thanks to `@using (Html.BeginForm("SendApplication", "Home", FormMethod.Post))` I send data to My actionResult.

My ActionResult:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SendApplication(App_AppTemp_Serv_PersInfModel appFile, int iIdServices)
    {           
        int iIdService = 0;            

        var serviceDetails = dbModel.SERVICES.Where(x => x.iIdSevices == iIdServices).FirstOrDefault();
        iIdService = serviceDetails.iIdSevices;

        if (bFile == true)
        {
            appFile.appModel.vFile = "Приклепленные файлы имеются";
        }
        else
        {
            appFile.appModel.vFile = "Приклепленных файлов нет";
        }            

        appFile.appModel.vDate = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now);

        try
        {
            dbModel.APPLICATIONS.Add(appFile.appModel);
            dbModel.SaveChanges();
            ModelState.Clear();
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            ViewBag.sErrorMessage = exc.Message;               
        }

        return View("~/Views/Home/ProblemForm.cshtml", appFile);
    }
```

But I can't to get the data from combobox, I don't know how?! Maybe use class and get class value, anyone have a idea for this?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can get the data from dropdownlist using the name of that control. It seems that  in your example `model.servicesModel` will be the name of dropdownlist. so in your controller get data using that property .

**for ex:** Assuming App_AppTemp_Serv_PersInfModel is your model, if no, change it accordingly

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SendApplication(App_AppTemp_Serv_PersInfModel appFile, int iIdServices)
    {  

            //dropdownlist selected value

            string selectedvalue =   appFile.servicesModel

           //other code
}
```

Hope it was helpful

Thanks

Karthik